# Building kibana dashboard programmatically

Tags: kibana-4

I am building an application which I am automating the loading of data into elastic search and then create a dashboard pro grammatically ( With a per defined Schema).I am using elastic search 2.1.1 ,log stash 2.1.1 and Kibana 4.3.1

I already have an kibana dashboard json file which I want to use a schema and accordingly I want to create dashboard for other index.